# Google SEO for dynamic multilanguage site

Tags: seo, php, meta-description

I have created a bilanguage site EN/DE
the language text are dynamically loaded from `EN.php` or `DE.php` depending on a `$language` variable.
How can I organise my code / pages for better SEO and how can I organise the tags description for both language.
Should I duplicate my full pages to www.mySite.com/en/ and www.mySite.com/de/ ??